# How to update function automatically when argument changes in AngularJS 1.6.6 ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I have `$scope.number` in my controller that is passed into 
`$scope.getArrayWithEvenNumbers()` function. What I want to get is automatically update `$scope.myArray` when `$scope.number` changes. Could you give me some hints how can I achieve that result ?

Thank you very much in advance!

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ba2b892f/5/)

Comment: javascript has observer, google it.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[dynamically updated array with $doCheck](https://jsfiddle.net/ba2b892f/6/)

I check the `$scope.oldNumber` with `$scope.number` in every digest cycle. When it changes, I run the `$scope.getArrayWithEvenNumbers()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **$watch**, please check this [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/0mt6t71v/) with your expected behaviour.

```
    $scope.myArray=[0];
    $scope.number = 2;
    $scope.$watch("number", function(){
        $scope.myArray.push($scope.number);
    });
```